# Mouting a modal so it is within the app and has access to contexts

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible using a hook to mount a modal within my React application so that it also has access to any contexts?

Currently I have this but it does not have access to context wrappers.

```
export const mountModal = (modalComponent) => {
  const modalRoot = document.getElementById(MODAL_ROOT_ID);
  const root = createRoot(modalRoot);
  root.render(
    cloneElement(modalComponent, {
      onRequestClose: () => {
        root.unmount();
      },
    })
  );
};
```

And within `_app.js` I have this:

```
<UserProvider user={user}>
  <ConnectProvider>
    {children}
    <div id={MODAL_ROOT_ID} />
  </ConnectProvider>
</UserProvider>
```

And to mount my modal i call: `mountModal(<MessageModal />)`
Now `MessageModal` wants to use some data from the `UserProvider` and `ConnectProvider`, but it doesnt have access and blows up.

I have tried `createPortal` but that also does not have access to the providers.